# cannot save Oracle SQL Developer nls_date_format

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I set the date/time format in preferences, database,NLS (Oracle SQL Developer).
So this is persistent (after reboot too).
But when I load a table the column shows only the date.
What can I do to solve this problem (export datarows is without time ....):

Thank you

Comment: I suspect nls settings precedence order. See my answer.

Comment: Is it possible you have a logon trigger that's setting the session NLS_DATE_FORMAT? What data type is the column - actually a `DATE`, not a string or a `TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: You can also set it explicitly in a login script that gets executed after your connection is established, defined in preferences, Database > Filename for connection startup script.

And, do you have 'Skip NLS Settings' checked in the preferences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the order of precedence of `NLS SETTINGS`. Client tool's setings are overrided by `locale-specific` nls settings. Either modify your OS `NLS_LANG' in environmental variable or use`session` level nls settings.

For example, use `to_char` with proper `format model` and as per your nls settings you would then see the desired format correctly.

Alternatively, you could also `ALTER SESSION` to make the session use a particular nls format.

You would love to read this nice post by Ed Stevens,http://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/nls_date_format/

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I solved this case with a logon script.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It would be nice if you add your answer by editing your question as explain what you did to solve your issue.